# How javascript deals with large numbers?

Tags: javascript, numbers

In this code from [wtfjs](https://wtfjs.com/wtfs/2010-02-12-almost-but-not-quite), apparently something goes wrong.

```
alert(111111111111111111111); // alerts 111111111111111110000
```

I did some tests and found that

```
11111111111111111 === 11111111111111112; //true
```

Can anyone specify why this happens?

Comment: because `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER < 11111111111111111` is true

Comment: JavaScript has no integers. All numbers are floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone specify why this happens?

`11111111111111111` is greater than [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), hence it is unsafe for any numerical-operation or comparison.

As mentioned in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER#Description)

> `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1` === `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2` evaluates to `true`